# Mounting case or generic mounting board

Tags: hardware, case

Generic hardware question. My Pi has multiple sensors wired to it and is functioning as desired. My question, is how can I mount these sensors to something? For example, one sensor I'm using is the [DHT22 temperature/humidity sensor](http://www.uugear.com/product/uugear-dht22-temperature-humidity-sensor-module/).

These sensors often have little holes (similar to the holes in the corners of the Pi board) that look like they can be used to mount the sensors onto something. What is this something? Is there a case, or some sort of board that can be used to mount these sensors (and the Pi board itself) in a flexible way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that there is an "absolute" answer to this question.  What I'd suggest you do is go to ebay and search on the phrase "project box" and have a skim of the results.  What you will find is a rich assortment of the types of boxes and cases which can be used to house a finished project (circuit, solution).  In order to firmly attach the "internals" of your project to the housing, some folks bolt the solutions in place.  These can be metal or plastic bolts of an appropriate diameter.  The pre-drilled holes in the PCBs of modules and circuits provides a recommended and easy attach point for these bolts.  Alternatives to bolts include glues (eg. hot glue), firm padding, zip ties and other ad-hoc techniques.  Your solution may have specific requirements.  For example, heat conduction, air flow (for heat dissipation or sensors), line of sight (IR LEDs) etc etc.

Comment: Thanks. That's the key I was looking for. Project box seems like it will work. I'll have to drill my own holes where I want them, and work around my special requirements. But this gets me pointed in the right direction. Was running into dead ends in my Google searches. I knew there had to be something generic.

Comment: Tupperware may be a cheaper and easier alternative; if you have "dollar stores" in your area they usually have a variety of shapes and sizes.  These are easy to drill mounting holes, hacksaw ports, epoxy onto, are non-conductive, and  are generally also pretty waterproof/dustproof if you need that and seal up any holes.  In a normal 20-30C environment the pi doesn't require any ventilation; if you monitor the core temp it should idle at 40-45C and peak at 50-55C under load.